# How to render form from different model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Post` model and a `post_status` model that contains a Boolean status attribute.

The database connection between Post and the `post_status` model is a `belongs_to` and `has_many`.

I want to render all posts from Post along with an accept/reject radio submit button that sets a Boolean value for `post_status` to the dashboard. The admin dashboard has currently only a view and controller.

I tried but I am getting error.

routes.rb:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :post_status
  end
get '/admin' => 'admin#index'
```

admin index.html.erb:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>User Email </th>
        <th>Uploaded Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= post.title %></td>
            <td><%= post.user.email %></td>
            <td><%= post.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') %></td>

            <% if post.post_status.empty? %>
              <td><%= " Pending" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <% post.post_status.each do |post_status| %>
                <% if post_status.false == false %>
                  <td><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% else  %>
                  <td ><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <td><%= "HERE I WANT TO RENDER THE FORM WITH ACCEPT REJECT AND SUBMIT BUTTON FOR EACH POST TO ADMIN DASHBOARD" %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You have a space between ‘:’ and post_status that should be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Should a post not just have a single status, which is then either `Rejected` or `Accepted`. So a `Post belongs_to :post_status` ; in other words: in the posts table there is a `post_status_id` column and with your buttons you are trying to set the state of the post?

Comment: hey nathanvda, each post has one status either accepted or rejected. but the status is saved in model name post_status model. and post is saved in post model. i want to render each post with accept and reject button in admin dashboard. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout `accept_nested_attribute` in Rails. It will help you update the associated tables as well.

"[Complex Rails Forms with Nested Attributes](https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/)" is a very good example of what you want.

Comment: hi i have gone through your references, i have no model for admin it has only controller and view. i have two model post and post_status. how can i combine this all and render form along with each post in admin view?

Comment: In your post model you'll add accept_nested_attribute: post_status.
In your view you'll add a form for each post to get status submitted.

Comment: When answering with a link it's very important to summarize the significant information in the answer in case the link rots and breaks. Without the summary your answer will be useless when the link breaks.

Comment: Can a post have only 1 `post_status` with it's flag set to true? Do all posts have the same set of post-statuses? If yes, your approach could be simplified a lot? I am trying to understand if this is just either a very bad example of a more complex problem, or if you have a very bad approach to what should be a simple problem (a post has just a single status and you need to set, from a selection of possible statuses?)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for this:

- `accept_nested_attribute`
- `Form Object`